# Azure Datafactory copying data from parquet

Tags: parquet, azure-data-factory

I am trying to set a simple copy from a parquet file to sql server using azure data factory data copy task.

The parquet file is exported from snowflake database and contains one field which is all numeric values. The field definition in Snowflake which is carried over to the parquet file is numeric (38,0).

I have set the data factory pipeline with a copy task, the source is set to the blob container with the parquet file, sink is set to SQL. When trying to preview the source data, I get the following error:

Column PRODUCT_ID of primitive type FixedLenByteArray, original type Decimal contained an invalid value for the given original type.

If I go to Mapping tab and I import schemas, I can see the product ID defined as Decimal

Any help, please?

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I am struggling with the same issue. Please help if you can.

Comment: unfortunately no, ended up using a different approach for this one

Comment: Thanks, which approach you ended up with? Please suggest